# Formatting numbers in python for display

Tags: python, formatting, numbers, format

I am trying to output a longer integer in a more readable manner. How can I format it as a string with spaces after a certain number of digits?

For example, I would like `12345678` to be output as `1234 56 78`

Comment: How is `1234 56 78` more readable than `12345678`?

Comment: do you mean 12 34 56 78?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is use `re` module, match the number with regex and reformat it:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})", r"\1 \2 \3", "12345678")
# '1234 56 78'
```

Or for readability you might want to format it with a thousand separator:

```
"{:,d}".format(12345678)
# '12,345,678'
```

Comment: Not sure what would be OP's expected output for `1234567` will be but this return `1234567` instead of `1234 56 7`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary The regex option is pretty restricted, and I can't come up with one that is general without knowing the number of digits and format requirement beforehand. So I guess this is just an option at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using a combination of `itertools` and `str.join()`:

```
>>> from itertools import zip_longest
>>> 
>>> def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

>>> def pretty_print(start, number, delim=' '):
    number = str(number)
    end = delim.join(''.join(g) for g in grouper(number[start:], 2, ''))
    return number[:start] + delim  + end

>>> number = 12345678
>>> pretty_print(4, number, ' ')
'1234 56 78'
>>> pretty_print(4, number, ',')
'1234,56,78'
>>> pretty_print(4, number, '|')
'1234|56|78'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> from itertools import islice

>>> def solve(num, n=4):
...     s = str(num)
...     fmt = [n] + [2] * ((len(s) - n) // 2);
...     it = iter(s)
...     return ' '.join(''.join(islice(it, x)) for x in fmt)

>>> solve(12345678)
'1234 56 78'

>>> solve(1234567890)
'1234 56 78 90'
```

Answer (score -1):

If the number is always going to be 8 digits, you need do nothing more complicated than use a simple [string formatting spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> '{}{}{}{} {}{} {}{}'.format(*str(12345678))
1234 56 78
```

If you could have, say, any even number of digits of length 2 or greater, and you want to have the first up-to 4 digits grouped, and then the following digit pairs grouped after that, you can still make this work pretty easily:

```
>>> digits8 = str(12345678)
>>> ('{}{}' + ' '.join('{}{}' for _ in range(len(digits)//2-1))).format(*digits)
1234 56 78
>>> digits6 = str(123456)
>>> ('{}{}' + ' '.join('{}{}' for _ in range(len(digits)//2-1))).format(*digits)
1234 56
>>> digits4 = str(1234)
>>> ('{}{}' + ' '.join('{}{}' for _ in range(len(digits)//2-1))).format(*digits)
1234
>>> digits2 = str(12)
>>> ('{}{}' + ' '.join('{}{}' for _ in range(len(digits)//2-1))).format(*digits)
12
```

As a function:

```
def special_format(number):
    digits = str(int(number))
    if len(digits)%2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('Number must have an even number of digits.')
    return ('{}{}' + ' '.join('{}{}' for _ in range(len(digits)//2-1))).format(*digits)
```

Now you can just do this:

```
>>> special_format(12345678)
'1234 56 78'
>>> special_format(123456)
'1234 56'
>>> special_format(12345678123456)
'1234 56 78 12 34 56'
>>> special_format(12)
'12'
```

Comment: This answer does exactly what the OP asks in an uncomplicated way. I am mystified as to why someone would downvote it.